# SAS Program to add salary

Tags: sas

I want to sum the salary after first two observation of the table.
1st two observation will remain same, rest should be added as shown below

```
Name    salary  Name    salary
subrat  10      subrat  10
abhi    20      abhi    20
milan   100     other   1000
sam     200         
sudhir  300         
muna    400
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data want;
 set have end = eof;
 if      _N_ in (1 2 3) then new_salary = salary;
 else if _N_ > 3        then new_salary + salary;

 if eof then name = "Other";

 if _N_ in (1 2) or eof;

drop salary;
rename new_salary = salary;
run;
```